# Python - make a list

Tags: python, list

How can I turn something like this: (not a file)

Edit: It's what I get when I print this:

```
adjusted_coordinate_list = str(adjusted_X_coordinate) + ',' + str(Y_coordinate)

1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
```

into this:

```
['1,1','1,2','1,3','1,4',1,5']
```

Comment: Your input is a string?

Comment: where those will be stored??, what is the type of input

Comment: If its not a file then what is it? Is it a string ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.splitlines` to split over boundaries of string and needed a `list`.

```
s = """1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5"""
print s.splitlines()

['1,1', '1,2', '1,3', '1,4', '1,5']
```

Comment: @user2971812 check the solution.

Comment: The result I'm getting is

    ['1,1']
['1,2']
['1,3']
['1,4']
['1,5']

Comment: @user2971812 show the code what you are trying and from where you are taking the input?

Comment: @user2971812 if you find answer correct and helping please mark correct an pramote me on S.O :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are looping over this command to get the input you described. I'm assuming something like this:

```
for foo in bar:
    adjusted_coordinate_list = str(adjusted_X_coordinate) + ',' + str(Y_coordinate)
    print adjusted_coordinate_list
```

In order to get all the results in a clean list, you would do something like this:

```
adjusted_coordinate_list = []
for foo in bar:
    new_elem = "%s,%s" % ( adjusted_X_coordinate, Y_coordinate )
    adjusted_coordinate_list.append( new_elem )
```

Your `adjusted_coordinate_list` will now contain a list of all the adjusted coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this pseudo code

```
ans_list = []
for each row:
    row = row.strip()
    ans_list.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this:

```
my_cor =[]
#some loop
    my_cor.append(str(adjusted_X_coordinate) + ',' + str(Y_coordinate))
print my_cor
```