# How to create a list out of integers list?

Tags: list, integer

I have a list of integers that looks like this when performing the print command:

0

1

0

1

1

I want to create a list out of it: [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
How to do it?
I cannot find such information anywhere :(

Comment: Add python to the tag list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27171335/1644901

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """0
1
0
1
1"""
integers = map(int, s.splitlines())
```

idea taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27171335/1644901